# per message acknowledgement in Kafka / RabbitMQ

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, producer-consumer

We have a working rabbitmq .implementation , due to volume, we are planning to switch to kafka.

I have a doubt at one point.

In rabbitMQ when the consumer consumes the message from the Q the message goes to a different stage  , unacked stage. the client/consumer takes some time to process the message, upon successful process, it sends an acknowledgement to the Q and the message gets deleted from the Q. if unsuccessful, after a defined period if the Q doesnt get an acknowledgement, the message is appended at the end of the Q . In this way we dont loose any message.

With my little knowledge in Kafka I understand that if for example message 100 was not successfully processed, the offset was not increased, but it will be increased if message 101 is processed successfully . So I lost the message 100.

Is there a way to guarantee that none of the messages will be lost .

Comment: You'd have to implement a Dead Letter Queue (DLQ).

Comment: Why not look at Solace as a closer messaging replacement to Rabbit? Similar APIs + semantics (e.g. per-message ACKs), but better volume handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same question. If I want to put in a simple way, RabbitMQ keeps a count of each

1. published and not consumed
2. published , consumed and not acknowledged messages.

Kafka doesnt, so u cant have it ready made, you have to implement it urself.

There are options available though, use kmq, performance will become less than 50% , have a look

https://softwaremill.com/kafka-with-selective-acknowledgments-performance/

Answer (score 2):

Kafka doesn't remove messages from topics unless it reaches one of the `log.retention.bytes` `log.retention.hours` `log.retention.minutes` `log.retention.ms` configs. so if offset increases you don't lose previous messages and you can simply change offset to the position that you want.

Comment: @ admin , my consumer was not keeping the track, and we have hundreds of clients , consuming messages RabbitMQ. They consume and acknowledges back for each message. and RabitMQ takes care of deleting a successfully consumed message, and publishing back again to Q for the unsuccessful ones. Now if the offset has moved ahead for a client without processing a message , how the client consume the same message again, without changing at clients end.

Answer (score 0):

Your message offset will not be increased unless you poll for new messages. So you must be concerned about reprocessing your message.

If you want to store the result of your data processing to Kafka cluster, you can use [transaction feature of Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/). This way you can support exactly once delivery. All of your changes will be saved or none of them will be stored.

Another approach is to make your processing scenario idempotent. You will assign a unique ID for each message in Kafka. When you process the message, you store the ID, in a database. After crash, you check your message ID is already processed by looking at the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should read a little bit about how message consumption in Kafka works.  Here's a link to the consumer section of the official Kafka docs:  https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#theconsumer

Basically, in Kafka, messages are only deleted after enough time has passed, and that is configured using the `log.retention.hours`, `log.retention.minutes` and `log.retention.ms` like @Amin has said.

In Kafka, any number of consumers can start consuming messages from any topic, at any moment, regardless of whether other consumers are already consuming from that same topic.  Kafka keeps track of where each consumer is, on each topic/partition, using offsets that are stored in Kafka itself.  So, if your consumer needs to consume message 100, like you described in your question, you can simply "rewind" to the desired message, and start consuming normally again.  It doesn't matter if you had previously consumed it, or if other consumers are reading from that topic or not.

From the official Kafka docs:

> A consumer can deliberately rewind back to an old offset and
>   re-consume data. This violates the common contract of a queue, but
>   turns out to be an essential feature for many consumers. For example,
>   if the consumer code has a bug and is discovered after some messages
>   are consumed, the consumer can re-consume those messages once the bug
>   is fixed.

Comment: Thanks @mjuarez , My scenario is a bit different , let me explain, so I have only one consumer/reader per Topic, if I have multiple, they are for parallelism, so they will read/consume different messages. But the consumer/reader when fails to process a message, and forwards to the next, may be message will still remain in kafka, but it will keep increasing the offset, reading only the new messages.SO the one which failed, wont be processed again . For rabbitMq it was easy, as it will move the message back to the Q . Kafka keeps one offset per consumer, RabbitMQ per message.

Comment: Just configure your client to read the kafka messages 1 at a time and only commit offsets after you have sucessfully processed each message and then you will have similar behavior to rabbitmq (only faster when using topic partitions for sharding and multiple consumers in a common consumer group) It will be slower than the normal mode where Kafka clients consume messages in batches but still faster

Comment: Also kafka clients typically keep one offset per partition per consumer group so a topic with 16 partitions and 4 consumers in a single consumer group would keep 16 offsets (one per partition).

Comment: @Hans that is a working solution, but that will eventually make the process slow. Is there any alternative, else we have to stick with old RabbitMq

Comment: The alternative is that you poll for batches of Kafka messages and manage your own offsets. If you have to skip a message then you write its offsets into a dead message queue or an external non-Kafka system for later reprocessing.